# How to do reply.continue(data) in newer versions of hapi

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, hapi.js, hapi

I am using older hapi version previously (version~16.x.x) Now i am upgrading its version to >18. In 16.x.x hapi version reply.continue(data) is feasible. But in newer versions, continue is no longer a method. How can we send that response(data) now ?

P.S:- The data/response i have to send is of type object

Answer (score 0):

reply.response(data) reply can be interchangeably used with h(response toolkit)
In case of error scenarios, just throw a boom error
if its authentication function
we have to use return h.authenticated(data) and h.unauthenticated(data)